# Xamarin, Android: ImageView.SetColorFilter() has NO effect whatsover on my ImageView?

Tags: android, xamarin, android-imageview

I have an `imageView` that uses an alpha channel, is round and basically made up only from black outlines. In a simple instance, I need to, however, display the `imageview` not as black, but as white. Everything else needs to stay the same. After a bit of googling, this is what I came up with:

```
ImageButton btnHeader = new ImageButton(this);
btnHeader.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.mainmenu_btn_news_bol);
btnHeader.SetColorFilter(new Color(Color.White), PorterDuff.Mode.SrcIn);
```

This should at least have some effect on the `ImageView` , but it just doesn't. It is, as if the 3rd line of code just gets jumped. Can anyone maybe explain to me if this is a bug or me?

Comment: Setting the color filter like that affects only the source image, not the background. That is, if you do `btnHeader.SetImageResource(...)` instead, it'll filter that. If you're specifically trying to filter the background, you'll have to set the filter on the background drawable directly: `btnHeader.Background.SetColorFilter(...)`.

Comment: Hey thanks mate! Put this as an answer, so I can accept it. Works perfectly! :) There is just one more thing: I use the same ImageButton twice in the same activity. Now both are colored white, instead of only the one where the filter is applied to. Can you help me out again? :)

Comment: Yeah, you can mutate the drawable first, so it doesn't share a common state with others created from the same resource. Insert a `Mutate()` call in there: `btnHeader.Background.Mutate().SetColorFilter(...)`. (I think that's right. I'm guessing at the Xamarin syntax.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting a color filter directly on the `ImageButton` will affect only its source image, not the background. That is, it will affect those images set with the `SetImage*()` methods. If that's what you mean to do, then simply change the `SetBackgroundResource()` call to `SetImageResource()`.

If, instead, you are trying to filter the background specifically, you'll need to set the filter directly on the background `Drawable`. For example:

```
btnHeader.Background.SetColorFilter(new Color(Color.White), PorterDuff.Mode.SrcIn);
```

Furthermore, separate `Drawable`s created from the same resource will share a common state by default, so if you have multiple `View`s using the same resource image, then setting a filter on one will affect all of the others, as well. You can force a new, separate state to be created for a particular `Drawable` by calling `Mutate()` on it first, before applying the filter. For example, with the background image:

```
btnHeader.Background.Mutate().SetColorFilter(new Color(Color.White), PorterDuff.Mode.SrcIn);
```

Comment: splendid. your knowledge is HIGHLY appreciated! :)